# Get key names if values is true

Tags: arrays, key

I need to get only the keys that has the value true, and return me the key name.

Question: I need to use the underscore or can not do in a simpler way?

```
{"desenvolvimento": true, "artigos": false, "design": true}
```

RESOLVED: More simple.

```
<span ng-repeat="(key, value) in item.tax.categorias" ng-if="value">{{key}}</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use a for in loop and test the prop!

```
for(var prop in obj){
 if(obj[prop] === true){
   // this is true
 }
}
```

I encourage you to read through [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference) for all the ways you can interact with objects and arrays

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: I'm in the angularjs, I can use is the javascript without correct problems?

Comment: Correct, You can use any native javascript from within angular.